# Was the opening of Rogue One designed to make you think this?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, music

It was well publicised before release that Rogue One did not have the traditional Star Wars opening crawl (and by extension, the theme tune). When I saw it, the opening scene after the "galaxy far, far away" title card opens with a very sudden chord that immediately made me think it was the beginning of John Williams' famous score and there was an opening crawl after all. Of course, this was not the case.

Was this a late addition to the film as a response to any fan complaints about the lack of the opening crawl? Was it just me who thought that?

[This](https://youtu.be/mf8oD3YT9IU) is the best clip I could find.

Comment: I thought the same thing. I'm interested in hearing what the reason was for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Composer Giacchino himself was a late addition to the film - he didn't have a lot of time to work on the score and was not given any instruction to deliberately mimic Williams:

> "Giacchino only had four and a half weeks to compose the music for the
>   film, beginning almost immediately after finishing production on
>   Doctor Strange."

From the same interview:

> **Kathleen Kennedy says they’re trying to break from some of the
>   traditional Star Wars tropes, like doing away with the opening crawl.
>   Sounds like that applies to the music as well?**
>
> Kathy said that to me, too — “No one is asking you to do what was done
>   before.” I feel it’s important to be me, but in this universe, we’re
>   working within. That was sort of the challenge. It was never sort of,
>   “Oh, you have to do this, this, and this.” It was always just: “Here
>   are the emotions that we need to cover.”

http://www.ew.com/article/2016/11/23/rogue-one-composer-michael-giacchino-music-star-wars-standalone -

*Opinion:
Other than the volume and surprise factor, I find little musical similarity between the two sections of score in question. Rogue One's track ["He's Here For Us"](https://open.spotify.com/track/53n7BB3bXGdiadKybuh0Pr) begins with a very fast note progression from low to high and then has the loud 'hit' or 'stinger' - compared with the "Main Title" of the saga films, which opens with all instruments playing a chord in unison.*

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: @Terriblefan, he's saying "*No, it was not designed to do this, as it is likely that Giacchino had other things to worry about with the time pressure, and anyways the two are different, musically, and therefore likely had no intention of tricking you*"

Comment: @Edlothiad That was added after my comment. It works now.

Comment: 1) I agree that the opening jump-scare music sounds nothing like the beginning of the Star Wars main theme. They're both loud & sudden, but that's it. 2) Even though they _say_ they weren't asking MG to mimic JW, there's a _lot_ of heavy speculation that Desplat wasn't asked to score the re-shot version of R1 because he was 'doing his own thing' for the first cut instead of making it sound like Star Wars should sound. So they fired him and got MG, and there was more than likely an understanding, spoken or otherwise, that they wanted MG to write music that more closely resembled JW's SW music.

Comment: I'd not heard that speculation about AD, do you have any more info on that @RedCaio ?

Comment: Upvoted this answer. I'd forgotten about the last minute re-scoring. I'm not a muso though, so to me both opening chords sound similar enough for it to at least be plausible.